# PHP echo Outputting JavaScript - script does not have same scope

Tags: php, javascript, variables, scope, echo

I am currently designing an HTML5 Canvas application and am using an Image Uploader so that users can upload local images to the server and then modify the image on canvas (as a number of manipulations to external sources will give you a security exception).

I have some JS included that goes something like this:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    var editImage = new Image; // Global scope; not in a function
    function setupCanvas() {}
</script>
```

Once the image has been successfully loaded I echo something like this:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("'.$upload_image.'"); 
    window.editImage=new Image(); 
    window.editImage.src=\''.$upload_image.'\'; 
    alert(window.editImage.src);
    setupCanvas();
</script>'
```

Now the output I get from the alert() statements are $upload_image. But when I check FireBug, it'll say that the editImage var that I have declared GLOBALLY in a separate script is still the ORIGINAL image source, NOT $upload_image. Furthermore, it'll say the setupCanvas() method that I have called will be UNDEFINED, although it is in the GLOBAL scope.

I am assuming when I do this with PHP there must be some scope issues - is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you sure that the JS is before the `echo` on the page?

Comment: This might very well be the case; how do I ensure it is AFTER the JS includes? I checked the HTML post-PHP action and the added script from PHP appears after the previous JS includes; would this be enough?

Comment: I tried including a test.php: echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(editImage.src);</script>'; and this seems to produce an undefined variable error - even if I place the include AFTER the other includes... although this might be due to image loading, but I still find this surprising.

Comment: Nope, PHP has completely nothing to do here. PHP stays thousand miles away from your scope. So, do all things without PHP first, with predefined images, etc. Debug it until it runs well, and only then make your JS generated by PHP. Got it?

Comment: Okay, I got it partially working thanks to your help!
I  copied the JS that I output with PHP into the area where I echo. This gave the SAME error; so it was NOT a PHP issue.

This was due to the document probably not loading; so I modified it to this:
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
       editImage=new Image(); 
       editImage.src='http://graffpic/uploads/fracture_1292689775.jpg'; 
       console.log(editImage.src); 
       setupCanvas();   
   });

Comment: This appears to work with JUST the JS - but when I do this with PHP I get that the $ symbol is UNDEFINED! What is the pure JS equivalent of this as I can't seem to depend on loading external libraries unless I include it again which is clunky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry code block in comments was unreadable, this is how I got it working with JUST javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   editImage=new Image(); 
   editImage.src='http://graffpic/uploads/fracture_1292689775.jpg'; 
   console.log(editImage.src); 
   setupCanvas();           
});
```

Only problem is when I output it with PHP it will say $ is UNDEFINED - so this is most likely a loading issue - can anyone give me a bit more detail on this and what to do? I COULD import the jQuery library AGAIN, but that seems clunky; either that or I could import the code fragment that is needed for $(document).ready() which is again quite clunky. Any help?

Comment: The issue ended up being that the output was being captured in an iFrame that I was using.. redirected the output elsewhere and it works... sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I hope it's actually your problem too. Not just a typo in your post, cause I've been scratching my head for ages with some code based on your example. It's not simply that your first code block reads,

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

Not

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

is it? (Note the missing 'a' in 'javascript' from the first line.)

Comment: Sorry about the example; I didn't copy and paste it directly. But I have spelt it correctly; will debug with pure JS for now- will edit now.

Comment: That's ok, no worries. It serves me right for not fully reading what I was looking at and just starting with a copy and paste myself. Let us know how it goes. I was thinking  that since you're dealing with images you might need to be waiting for `window.onload` but then you shouldn't see `setupCanvas` as `undefined` anyway, so I'm not sure.